# Showing “Press 'Ctrl'+'C'” to cancel filesystem checks in progress. Someone know how to solve this?

Tags: 20.04, error-handling

my computer is not starting and remain stacked when I am switching it on, someone knows how I can solve this without losing all my file. I have 1 month of work there I can't lose it. I attach the photo, Usually was staying here for 4-5 second.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default file system in Ubuntu nowadays is `ext4`. The big advantage of that file system is that it is much more quickly checked. The prompt you see, was common in the time the default file system was `ext3`. Then, periodically, a lengthy file system check was triggered during startup.

So I am surprised to learn you see this prompt regularly. Now, you seem to indicate that this prompt is stuck, i.e., booting does not proceed. That would suggest a more significant issue with the file system.

Since you do not appear to have a copy of all the data, the first thing to do probably is to boot into a live session, then try to mount the partition read-only. If that succeeds, you will be able to copy off data.

Then unmount the partition, and see if you can repair it manually using the `fsck` command. Use the `-f` option to force a full check - by default `fsck` does a quick test, and only automatically moves on with a full test when a previous full test was done more than a certain period ago.

Instead of working from a live CD, you can [boot into recovery mode](https://www.maketecheasier.com/boot-recovery-mode-ubuntu/). In the recovery menu, there is an option to do a file system check (fsck). Another option is to drop to a root prompt. Drawback of this approach is that you only have the terminal to control the system.

If a file system check fails, then you probably should reinstall, reformatting the partitions. If shortly after that, you experience this issue again, then expect that your hardware is failing.

Comment: It Seems its worked, I am actually copying all the file on an external hard disk thanks to and ubuntu USB stick, next I will reinstall the operative system, Hope this sad story will end well. @vanadium

Comment: It looks like it will! But please take the habit to have regular backups. This is really the first most important before anything else. Succes!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the first result on Google when searching for this issue, let me add another possible solution:

I did get stuck on this screen as well, but contrary to what the screen seems to suggest, it's not related to fsck at all. The key observation here is that normally, there's a loading spinner on this screen. Once the loading spinner disappears (as on the screenshot), we're supposed to launch into the graphical desktop. If this fails, then you'll also get stuck on this screen, even though it has nothing to do with fsck.

In my case (and I expect this to be not uncommon), this was caused by the default nouveau nvidia drivers not supporting my videocard (4080 super, it's likely to affect other newish cards too). To solve this, follow these steps:

1. Boot into Ubuntu recovery mode
2. In recovery mode: enable networking, dpkg, and then drop into the shell.
3. In the shell, run:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install nvidia-driver-550
   ```

In my case, I needed version 550, but this might change in the future. Check [https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Egraphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) for the current status.